# How to check if an Mongoid array field contains one or more items in another array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

If the field is an integer, then the following works:

```
User.where(id: [1,3,5])
```

But what if the field is an array? For example, the user has a field which is an array of `favorite_numbers`:

How to find users that have a favorite_number of 1, 3 or 5?

Rails 4.1.7
Mongoid 5.0.0

Edit: Added Mongoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not certain about Mongoid 5 but the `$in` operator should take care of unrolling the right side:

```
User.where(:favorite_numbers.in => [1,3,5])
# or
User.where(favorite_numbers: { :$in => [1,3,5] })
User.where(favorite_numbers: { '$in' => [1,3,5] })
User.where(favorite_numbers: { '$in': [1,3,5] }) # depending on Ruby version
```

MongoDB itself will take care of unrolling the `favorite_numbers` array.